# How to change date from dd to ddd for julian-day?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have julian day as "36" and I want to convert it to "036"similarly "01" as "001".  I tried like this for reading date and convert to julian date

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.None,
                               out date)) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Parse failed
}
DateTime myDT = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, new JulianCalendar());
JulianCalendar mycal = new JulianCalendar();
String dateInString = mycal.GetDayOfYear(myDT).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("ddd"));
```

If I use "ddd" displays Mon,Tue,Thu etc not "036". specific purpose I need julian day in three digits is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `"ddd"` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dddSpecifier) represents the abbreviated name of the day. That's why you get `Mon`,`Tue`,`Thu` etc.. It does not give you any numeric value.

But since you *already* use `GetDayOfYear` which returns day number in a year as an `int`, you can pad it with [`String.PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft) method like;

```
JulianCalendar mycal = new JulianCalendar();
String dateInString = mycal.GetDayOfYear(myDT).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```

For a single digit day numbers, like `1`, this will generate `001` but double digit day numbers like `36`, this will generate `036`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get leading zeros dor your date you can use leding zeros like this:

```
date1.Day.ToString("000")
```

If you want to use your `string` use [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) function of `string` like this:

```
date1.ToString("dd").PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Comment: Great job... i tried **String.PadLeft** method and it is working.  thank you @Soner Gönül & teo van kot. helped me a lot.